# CGridView nested CGridView with another model

Tags: gridview, yii

Is it possible to have gridview in gridview? Specifically to have the row expand/collapse to another gridview? If so, how would I go about this? Let's say I want to click on first_name, and then it can display that user's email and address.

```
$this->widget ( 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array (
    'id'=>'order-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
            //another model stuff//
            array('name'=>'first_name', 'header'=>'First Name'),
            array('value'=>array($this,'updateStatus'), 'header'=>'Update'),

    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`TbRelationalColumn`](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView/index.html#gridcolumns).

Comment: exactly what im looking for! Thanks!